# Workflow Milestone Engine

Tags: java, workflow, bpel, bpmn

I look for a java workflow engine that handles milestones. It shall enforce the sequence of milestones and allow to create time dependencies. Not the traditional BPMN business process flow (but rather a subset), not even sure if workflow engine is the proper term for my requirement.

Random Sample:

1. Customer provides credit card @ time t1 00:00
2. Customer start pumping petrol @ time t2 within 10 minutes after t1.
3. stops pumping @ time t3
4. Customer pays purchase @ time t4 within 5 minutes after t3
5. Customer gives feedback for survey, optional but only if t1 to t4 happened.

t1 to t4 must happen in sequence.

Any ideas ? I dont want to implement because at a later stage BPMN might come into the picture. I want to embed it into my EE EJB solution, not running as separate service.

Comment: guess I am looking into wrong direction ! Event-Driven-Architecture, ESP and CEP are the right tags !  
Interesting overview here: http://rulecore.com/CEPblog/?page_id=47

Answer (score 0):

Not keen to answer myself, but it is worth to look into
http://esper.codehaus.org/
http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-fusion.html